# Margin notes (or todo's) in ACM Transactions template

Tags: margins, todonotes

I want to add margin notes to a document I'm writing in the ACM Transactions format (it's still in draft form). However, it's quite difficult to use existing packages such as todonotes (which looks great) or ed, since the notes will always overfill the margins (resulting in compile errors).

Any idea what I can do about this?

Thanks!

Comment: did you already tried the default  `\marginnote[left]{right}`?

Comment: sorry, I meant `\marginpar`

Comment: Do you mean errors or warnings?  If it's just warnings about overfull hboxes, they are temporary anyway.  They'll go away when you stop printing the marginal notes to yourself.

Comment: They were errors. But I just defined my own TODO command now, since I wasn't able to figure it out. All packages I used gave errors w.r.t. overfull hboxes (even \marginpar). I guess this is because the transactions template defines very narrow margins.

Answer (score 3):

If your notes and todos are text only then you can hide them in PDF annotations in the margin using `\pdfmargincomment` of the [pdfcomment](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pdfcomment.html) package.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[svgnames,rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage[subject={Todo},author={Josef}]{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\pdfmargincomment[color=blue,icon=Note]{Put your notes or todos in here!}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]